# XSL element matching condition and display specific xml node element only

Tags: xml, xslt, conditional-statements, string-matching

I have this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
<metadata>
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords">marketing business</field>
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/PageTitle">PageTitle1</field>
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url">marketing business link</field>
</metadata>
<metadata>
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords">planning development</field>
 <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/PageTitle">PageTitle2</field>
 <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url">planning development link</field>
</metadata>
<metadata>
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords">learning development</field>
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/PageTitle">PageTitle3</field>
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url">learning development link</field>
</metadata>
```

and my XSL code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <body>
 <h2>Updated Tool Information:</h2>
 <table border="1">
   <xsl:for-each select="document/metadata/field">
   <tr>
   <xsl:if test = "@name = 'MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords' and contains(.,'development')">
      <td>Page Title: <xsl:value-of select="field[@name = 'MyWebsiteMetadata/PageTitle']"/></td>
      <td>URL: <xsl:value-of select="field[@name = 'MyWebsiteMetadata/active_url']"/>    </td>
   </xsl:if>      
   </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

My goal is to have a string match with 'development' for example and the page will display the Page title and URL only.

My expected results should display like this -

1. Page Title: PageTitle2 URL: planning development link
2. Page Title: PageTitle3 URL: learning development link

Unfortunately, the code above is not displaying anything, it's blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
   <xsl:for-each select="document/metadata/field">
   <tr>
   <xsl:if test = "@name = 'MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords' and contains(.,'development')">
      <td>Page Title: <xsl:value-of select="field[@name = 'MyWebsiteMetadata/PageTitle']"/></td>
      <td>URL: <xsl:value-of select="field[@name = 'MyWebsiteMetadata/active_url']"/>    </td>
   </xsl:if>      
   </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

you want

```
   <xsl:for-each select="document/metadata[field[@name = 'MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords' and contains(.,'development')]]">
   <tr>

      <td>Page Title: <xsl:value-of select="field[@name = 'MyWebsiteMetadata/PageTitle']"/></td>
      <td>URL: <xsl:value-of select="field[@name = 'MyWebsiteMetadata/active_url']"/>    </td>

   </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin Honnen
It worked! Appreciate all the help on this.

Comment: @syntaxcode, Welcome to Stackoverflow! Appreciation and thanks are welcome, but accepting the useful answer is much better. You can accept this answer by clicking the check mark on the left (just below the arrowheads) to make it appear green.